# Remove CQL_Filter from OpenLayers map

Tags: javascript, cql-filter, openlayers-2

I'm using **OpenLayers** to show my map with some layers. I've a field where I can add some filters with CQL code. I can successfully add a new filter to my map, and only the right points appear in my map but when I try to remove the filters it's deleting my Layer instead of my previous CQL_Filter result, so is **deleting ALL the points from the map**.

```
//My var map is previously declared
var layerFromMap = map.getLayersByName(input.name)[0];
//If my input is empty then I should delete the filters, like resetting the search
if (input.value.length > 0) {
    layerFromMap.mergeNewParams({ 'CQL_FILTER': input.value });
    layerFromMap.redraw();
} else {
    delete layerFromMap.params.CQL_FILTER;
    layerFromMap.redraw();
}
```

When input is empty `layerFromMapparams.CQL_FILTER` is deleting my layer from the map, so all the points are deleted. **Why is this happening**? **How can I only remove the filter so all the points appear again**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just find out how to do it and is very simple, just set the `CQL_FILTER` to `null`:

```
//My var map is previously declared
var layerFromMap = map.getLayersByName(input.name)[0];
//If my input is empty then I should delete the filters, like resetting the search
if (input.value.length > 0) {
    layerFromMap.mergeNewParams({ 'CQL_FILTER': input.value });
    layerFromMap.redraw();
} else {
    layerFromMap.mergeNewParams({ 'CQL_FILTER': null });
    layerFromMap.redraw();
}
```

Comment: If you are using newer versions of OL, this works well:

const params = layer.getSource().getParams();

delete params["CQL_FILTER"];

layer.getSource().updateParams(params);