# How to reset cql_filter of WMS on OpenLayers 3?

Tags: wms, openlayers, cql-filter

I can dynamically change the CQL filter, but I want to reset it to default (get WMS without any filter).

Class I am using  "ol.source.TileWMS" as source from GeoServer

Here is my code to which I used to update the CQL filter:

```
overlay_layer_definition_array[selected_layer].getSource().updateParams({  'LAYERS': Lay_Param[selected_layer][1] + ':'
        + Lay_Param[selected_layer][2]   ,'cql_filter': ''+strUser+strUser1+strUser2});
```

The above code works fine, but now I don't want to pass any filter, tried all of below

[How to immediately refresh ol.source.TileWMS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153554/how-to-immediately-refresh-ol-source-tilewms)  does not work

`refresh()` does not work

`'cql_filter': nil` does not work

`'cql_filter': 'nil'`  does not work

Comment: Just set it to null. Check link http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/141896/89518

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with 'cql_filter':undefined , and check the console to see if the parameter is sent to geoserver.

If it doesn't work, try with "delete", like this

```
var source = overlay_layer_definition_array[selected_layer].getSource();
delete source.params_['cql_filter']
```

Please notice that this is not a good solution, because you are modifying a private property, and upgrading ol3 may break your code, so it should be used only as a temporary solution...
In case, I suggest you to ask for a "public" way to delete a param.

Otherwise, you can recreate the layer instead.

Comment: yes there must be a standard way in the openlayer-3 to delete/reset params .  This can be treated a bug/incompleteness. for now i can set it as  'cql_filter': 'gid>-1' this will work as reset because all my layers are from pg so they have gid and by default my case a id can never be negative so this does the trick , but main problem still remains.